# Reputation on Meta vs Main site

Tags: support

I've seen that reputation here on meta tends to reflect your reputation on the primary site.  But does reputation increases here on meta transfer back to the main site?  Are these two accounts linked?  (Or are they actually just one account that is shared between the two places?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I infer from your account that you're not familiar with [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) or most of the other stack metas. So while this next part seems superfluous, it's not:

[Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) is the only "site meta" that has an independent rep system. It's normally just referred to as "Meta" (I usually call it metaso as a distinguisher). Sometimes people will refer to a site meta like the one we're on now as a "meta". Notice the upper/lower distinguisher (hence why I call it metaso). The reason for that site to have an independent rep system is because it is

1. the initial testing ground for all bugfixes and new features
2. the place to suggest new features (where voting determines community merit)
3. The place for all community problems and reporting (doesn't really have anything to do with rep)
4. The last of the trinity sites (which includes superuser and serverfault) so they still have significant historical SEO and the like.
5. The only meta with edit privileges for regular users.

So the point of all that was this: Metaso has it's own rep system, but it is the *only* meta on the SEI network that does. On all the other metas, all voting is free, but is also without merit back to the votee. So downvotes cause nothing for either party<sup>1</sup>, nor do upvotes infer a benefit. The downside is also, no editing for normal situations on a meta. If you need that, flag the post and we'll get to it as soon as we're reasonably able.

<sup>1</sup> They do run the potential of you're being banned for successive downvotes, but those are edge cases, not to be considered "normally". Nobody so far has even *begun* to run this risk on dba that I'm aware of.